# curl url php post method strange json results

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to post a keyword to a url and then get the json results back. This is my code for the php:

```
$url = 'http://www.hiddendomain.com/tld';
$fields = array( 'keyword' => urlencode('referralcode') );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$test = json_decode($result);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

The intended results from what I can tell is supposed to return json encoded data. But when I attempt to decode it I just get a value of 1, and not the actual data.

Here's the actual response I get back

```
 [{"domain":"referralcode.com","status":"taken","tld":"com","url":"http:\/\/referralcode.com"},{"domain":"referralcode.co.uk","status":"taken","tld":"co.uk","url":"http:\/\/referralcode.co.uk"},{"domain":"referralcode.net","status":"taken","tld":"net","url":"http:\/\/referralcode.net"},{"domain":"referralcode.eu","status":"available","tld":"eu","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.eu"},{"domain":"referralcode.org","status":"available","tld":"org","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.org"},{"domain":"referralcode.me","status":"available","tld":"me","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.me"},{"domain":"referralcode.us","status":"available","tld":"us","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.us"},{"domain":"referralcode.co","status":"taken","tld":"co","url":"http:\/\/referralcode.co"},{"domain":"referralcode.ca","status":"available","tld":"ca","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.ca"},{"domain":"referralcode.info","status":"available","tld":"info","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.info"},{"domain":"referralcode.de","status":"available","tld":"de","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.de"},{"domain":"referralcode.tv","status":"available","tld":"tv","url":"https:\/\/www.uniteddomains.com\/domain\/namecheck?et_cid=2\u0026et_lid=2\u0026domain=referralcode.tv"}]
```

Am I missing something in regards to the normal process of json decoding or is this just a strange result?

Answer (score 2):

Setting:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

does the trick. Sorry about that.